# Android: How to remove arrow down icon next to EditTextPreference entry?

Tags: android, listpreference

The preference activity gets inflated by invoking

> addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

and here are the preferences.xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_categ_update_label">
    <ListPreference android:title="@string/pref_label"
        android:key="update_interval" 
        android:entries="@array/update_names" android:entryValues="@array/update_values" />


</PreferenceCategory>


<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_categ_evernote_label">

    <EditTextPreference android:title="@string/pref_dialog_edit_username"
        android:key="prefUsername" 
        android:positiveButtonText="@string/save_pref"
        android:negativeButtonText="@string/cancel_pref"  />

    <EditTextPreference android:title="@string/pref_dialog_edit_password"
        android:key="prefPassword"  
        android:positiveButtonText="@string/save_pref"
        android:negativeButtonText="@string/cancel_pref"             
        android:password="true" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

everything looks okay, but EditTextPreference entries (2 and 3) have arrow-down icons next to them, just like ListPreference (1) does. Why is it so and how can I remove these icons as they look irrelevant?

The screenshot is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZUr7.png

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want the arrows in preferences then use -

```
**android:widgetLayout="@null"**
```

And if you want to give some custom image in preference right hand side then use -

```
**android:widgetLayout="@layout/pref_custom_image"**
```

where, **pref_custom_image.xml** will look like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrows are there to let you know that clicking on that preference is going to take you somewhere else.  In the case of the `ListPreference` it indicates that it goes to another "screen" in the case of the `EditTextPreference` it indicated that it is going to pop up a dialog.  If yo don't like it you can create a new style for it and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought these arrows were layout bugs)

Comment: And what's the minimum implementation to achieve that? (I want the same functionality and dont want to write whole Preference myslef)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is safe and good way, but you can remove the icon if you extend the EditTextPreference class like that:

By overiding the `getView()` method you can change what is drawn in the list. I'm using the original view and search it for all images (recursivly) and changing their `visibility` to `GONE`.

```
public class EditTextPreferenceNoImage extends EditTextPreference {
public EditTextPreferenceNoImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public EditTextPreferenceNoImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public EditTextPreferenceNoImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(convertView, parent);
    changeImagesVisibility(view, View.GONE);
    return view;
}

private void changeImagesVisibility(View view, int visibility) {
    log.debug("child:" + view.getClass());
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup ll = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
            changeImagesVisibilitz(ll.getChildAt(i), visibility);
        }
    } else if (view instanceof ImageView) {
        log.debug("visiblitz : " + (visibility == View.VISIBLE));
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
        image.setVisibility(visibility);
    }

}}
```

Comment: i think disableImages is modify changeImagesVisibilitz？so i edit your post

Comment: You are right, I simplified this code from my real one and forget to change this method call

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this same issue, I've found a super simple solution to get rid of the arrow on preference items (technically, it gets rid of anything that would appear there--arrow image checkbox, etc.). In your preferences.xml, set the value for Widget Layout to "@null".