# Remove icon of DialogPreference appearing on PreferenceActivity screen

Tags: android, dialog-preference

Does anyone know how to remove the icon of `DialogPreference` appearing on `PreferenceActivity` screen?
The icon having down arrow bounded inside a circle (▼), which appears on the preference list.

Similar question to this one: [Android: How to remove arrow down icon next to EditTextPreference entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822077/android-how-to-remove-arrow-down-icon-next-to-edittextpreference-entry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, I've found the other way around is to create regular `Preference`, and implement `OnPreferenceClickListener` to display a dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Try `setDialogIcon(null)` on your `DialogPreference`.

Comment: No, it's the icon appearing when displaying the dialog, not the icon appearing on `PreferenceActivity`

Comment: Your question was Does anyone know how to remove the icon of DialogPreference **appearing on PreferenceActivity screen? ** But anyways, my answer WAS a suggestion for getting rid of it in the dialog.